# Watcher on a element attribute to change the elements inner html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

The div's content is being filled up with the content of the attribute sk-placeholder. I have an if statement which will fill up the content of the div with a certain text or an empty string depending on the boolean viewer.building.

```
<div contentEditable="[[viewer.building]]" class="course-description"
ng-model="viewer.course.description" sk-replace
sk-placeholder="[[viewer.building && 'Summarise the content of your course
by  writing a short blurb. You can add a more elaborate description on
the next  page.' || '']]"></div>
```

When the placeholders content changes, an event needs to be fired, to empty the content of the div. I made a new directive called sk-replace that should do that. But the event is not firing.

```
SEK.app.directive("skReplace", function ()
{
    return {
        restrict:'AEC',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
             scope.$watch(attrs.skPlaceholder.value, function(v) {
                v = attrs.skPlaceholder;
                if(v.length < 1){
                    elem.html('');
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The function is executed on page load. But not when the placeholder's content changed. (this is done by a button btw)

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [**$observe**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) instead :

```
attrs.$observe('skPlaceholder', function (value) {
  if (value.length < 1) {
    elem.html('');
  };
});
```

Comment: When I change the attributes value with plain javascript on document.ready, the event is not fired. Any idea why?

Comment: Yeah because angular has no evidence of it. You should use a `$digest` or `$apply` to refresh the value

Comment: I need the observe method to run again when the document is finished loading. So it should be the last thing javascript does. I tried adding this at the bottom of my document : $document.ready(function(){
            attrs.$digest();
        });

Because now, the directive is being run when the value of the placeholder isn't replaced yet. Which leaves the element hidden.

Comment: Is it okay that I do this at the bottom of my html document? Because it says $document not defined. I changed it to angular.element(document) instead, now it says that scope isn't defined. It seems as if angular.js is not loaded.

Comment: I though you want to do it in your directive, and you still need to inject `$document` in it. Remember to open a new question if you have still problems :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61885/discussion-between-axel-vankrunkelsven-and-apercu).

Answer (score 1):

`$watch` takes either a function or a string as the first parameter, so you have two options (three if you use `observe` instead). Option one (bind to scope):

```
scope.val = attrs.skPalceholder.value;    
scope.$watch('val', function(v) {
  if(v.length < 1) {
    elem.html('');
  };
});
```

Option two (return value from function)

```
scope.$watch(function() {
  return attrs.skPlaceholder.value;
}, function(v) { 
  if(v.length < 1){
    elem.html('');
  };
});
```

Edit - I see `observe` was covered in another answer, and might be more elegant than the watcher solutions. Up to you.

Comment: I used the observe method and works perfectly. Thanks a lot to both of you!